# Possible methods to control the voltage of a variable 3 phase power supply for an electromagnet?

Tags: control, power-electronics, three-phase

The only solution I can think of is a three phase variable transformer, are there other methods? If so, what is the standard or accepted method to control the voltage of a variable 3 phase power supply? If there is no standard, what are some common methods?

Comment: For those suggesting that this question is too broad, could you please comment how I could improve this question? Thanks!

Comment: concentrate on one aspect? currently I could imagine the questions you ask being answered by multiple books...

Comment: Okay fair enough, I'll modify it.

Comment: What type of electromagnet is it? What is it used for? I'm asking because, if it is just used as an alternative to a permanent magnet then there's probably a better solution than what I offered in my answer.

Comment: It will be used for a mag lev system. Either a single coil with multiple with multiple windings or multiple coils lying in the same plane. Both options are being considered.

Comment: So yes. The 3ph voltage will be rectified. Unless there is a way to use AC to achieve magnetic levitation?

Comment: Realistically you are hoping to supply dc to the electromagnet so why are you asking for a 3ph solution (only to rectify this and bring it back to dc). What voltage and what current (dc please). What supply voltage.

Comment: 3 phase was suggested by my supervisor because of the huge forces this electromagnet needs to produce. I see what you mean though, it seems strange if it is just going to be rectified. I need to ask him a few questions but I cant get hold of him until at least Friday. This is for a university project that I have only just started. The specific part I am looking at is the power electronics between the micro controller and electromagnet. I'm still trying to get hold of data or a mathematical model of the system, so at the moment all I know is that the forces for the mag lev need to be huge.

Comment: Look into something called "phase control".  Sort of like an incandescent lamp dimmer but much larger and capable of running on 3-phase power.  Very common and relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was made before the OP mentioned that the target load is an electromagnet. I suspect that if the electromagnet is purely dc (i.e. uses a 3ph rectifier) then a dc solution will be simpler.

Original answer: -

If you considered a 3ph motor controller inverter you would get a variable output frequency and voltage: -

[image]

This method is clearly tailored for a motor but there is no reason why the main power electronic components couldn't be modified to produce a 3 phase, variable frequency and variable voltage power supply.